# How would I approach a where I need PID to decrease 2D error

Tags: ros, pid, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. I am using the drone to follow a bunch of red dots that I have detected using my OpenCV algorithms.

### Problem Space

Now I need to move the drone. To do this,  I believe the best technique would be a PID. However, looking at the documentation for a [PID](http://wiki.ros.org/pid), it takes on a `/setpoint/data`, `/state/data` and outputs a `/control_effort/data`. How would I deal with the 2D situation I have right now? These topics only take `std_msgs/Float64` to my knowledge.

I also eventually want to adapt this for a 3D problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255376/how-would-i-approach-a-where-i-need-pid-to-decrease-2d-error/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-02-23**:
Looking quickly at the package,
it is a 1d PID. If you want to control your drone in position, x,y,z, you can launch 3 PID node which you can rename in PID_x, PID_y, PID_Z for exemple. The fact that it is 1d allow you to tune it for each direction ( for a quadrotor, x = y but z will differ ).

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
@TTDM any chance that we can get a 2D PID node?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
@TTDM also, how would I go about creating the 3D PID node? Is there a package? Do we have to launch 3 different PID nodes?

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-02-23**:
In my opinion, if you want to use this package, the easiest solution would be to launch 3 nodes with [different names](http://answers.ros.org/question/31944/rosrun-node_name/),
Or, you can also directly create a PID from scratch, for a simple implementation, this is only a few lines of code.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-03-07**:
@TTDM Please add this as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in my comments:

This package is a one dimensionnal PID, if you want to use this package, in my opinion, the easiest solution would be to launch 3 nodes with different names,
[This link](http://answers.ros.org/question/31944/rosrun-node_name/) contains the explanation on how to change a node name.

Edit: AndyZe noticed that in the [documentation of the package](http://wiki.ros.org/pid) ( which is already linked in the question) , there is already a well detailed example on how to setup multiple PIDs ( in sec 5.4 : Support for multiple controllers ).

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-03-07**:
To add to this, there is already an example of launching multiple PID nodes. You could just change the namespace in the launch file of the example. [link](http://wiki.ros.org/pid#Support_for_multiple_controllers_.28with_example.29)

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-03-07**:
I went past the documentation of the package a little bit too fast but the exemple is pretty clear indeed ;)
I'm adding your link in my answer if that's ok for you.